# Moving an input and image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've the following HTML code:

```
<form id="update_status_imgform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ajaximage/update_status_image.php">
<div class="file_button_container2" id="btn_contaier_browse"><input type='file' name='upd_img' id='upd_img' /></div>
</form>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.file_button_container2,
  .file_button_container2 input {
       height: 24px;
       width: 30px;
       cursor: pointer;
   }

   .file_button_container2 {
       background-image: url(../images/assets/camera.png);
       z-index: 1;
       position: relative;
       top: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       opacity:0.4; 
       filter:alpha(opacity=40);
   }

   .file_button_container2 input {
       -moz-opacity:0 ;
        filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
   }
```

Now, this is fine for IE and works great but for Safari and Chrome it seems to do the following:

A) Shift in front of another image to it's left (which has a width of 100px)
B) When clicked on not open up the file browser to select a photo

How can I resolve this so it shifts right 110 pixels and also opens a file upload select box in Chrome and Safari while effectively not changing at all in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by doing the following:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<style type="text/css">
.file_button_container2,
  .file_button_container2 input {
       text-align: left;
       padding-left: 110px;
   }

   .file_button_container2 {
       background-position: right;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
</style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```